# Why do some soldiers wear yellow uniforms?

Tags: movie, enders-game

Here we see the Launchies group with a couple of people dressed in yellow, while the rest are in white.

[image: Ender's Game production still #1]

Here we see the mess hall with Ender and Petra in Salamander Army. In the background is a soldier wearing yellow.

[image: Ender's Game production still #2]

What is the significance of the yellow suit? If the yellow suit is for Launchies, why aren't the rest of the soldiers in picture #1 in some state of changing from white to yellow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sets of clothes were [auctioned shortly after the film was released](https://propstoreauction.com/view-auctions/info/id/21/). The yellow suits are identified by the props department as "*Flight Suits*" and the white clothes as "*Night Clothes*"

> [Yellow Launchie Flight Suit #1](https://propstore.com/product/enders-game/ender-wiggins-asa-butterfield-yellow-launchie-flight-suit-1/)
>
> [image]
>
> [Asa Butterfield Night Clothes](https://propstoreauction.com/view-auctions/catalog/id/21/lot/2446/ENDER-S-GAME-Ender-Wiggin-rsquo-s-Asa-Butterfield-Night-Clothes)
>
> [image]

It might interest you to learn that both sets went for about $80

Answer (score 11):

In the book, armies each had their own [color combinations](http://ansible.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_School_Army) for identification. However, in the second picture, the shoulder patches seem to indicate three different armies (salamander, rat, and asp? [Note the photos of army insignias on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1731141/mediaindex?ref_=tt_pv_md_sm)) all wearing the same uniform.

I suspect the yellow uniform is indeed what the Launchies wear before being assigned to an actual army.  Note that Graff is there addressing Ender in public in the top picture; if I recall correctly, Graff largely avoided Ender during the bulk of his time during Battle School, so it seems most likely that the scene in question would have been right around when Ender first arrived.

The white outfits do not seem to be uniforms at all, but rather possibly school-issued pajamas or other sleep wear.

Comment: Yep, they're just unskilled, untrained yellow bellied Launchies. They wear the yellow until they're promoted to an army. Ender got promoted to Salamander very quickly. The white is as you say, PJs.

Comment: Incidentally, the use of PJs directly contradicts the book, which says they slept naked.  But *obviously* that wouldn't have worked in a film with 12-year-old kids, and there are much worse things to complain about them changing.